# Python BusinessHours Library Error

Tags: python

I am using the BusinessHours PyPi package to calculate the business days and public holidays between to dates however it seems to be spitting out a 'not defined' error (below).

They give you an example on how to call the package.

```
eg: Class:  BusinessHours(datetime1,datetime2,worktiming=[9 ,18],weekends=[6,7],holidayfile=None)

Class Parameters:
datetime1   - The datetime object with the starting date.
datetime2   - The datetime object with the ending date.
worktiming  - The working office hours . A list containing two values start time and end time
weekends    - The days in a week which have to be considered as weekends sent as a list, 1 for monday ...  7 for sunday.
holidayfile - A file consisting of the predetermined office holidays.Each date starts in a new line and currently must only be in the format dd-mm-yyyy

from BusinessHours import BusinessHours
from datetime import datetime
testing = BusinessHours(datetime(2007,10,15),datetime.now())
print testing.getdays()
```

Using this information I made the below test script

```
from BusinessHours import BusinessHours
from datetime import datetime
holidaytextfile = 'holidays.txt' 

testing = BusinessHours(datetime(2013,02,01),datetime(2013,02,28),worktiming=[9 ,18],weekends=[6,7],holidayfile=holidaytextfile)
print testing.getdays()
```

My holiday file contains the following (just a random business day in Feb)

```
07-02-2013
```

When I run the script I get the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "business_days", line 9, in ?
print testing.getdays()
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/BusinessHours.py", line 63, in getdays
holidate = date(int(year) , int(month) , int(day))
NameError: global name 'date' is not defined
```

This is the section of code from the package.

```
 60             for definedholiday in definedholidays:
 61                 flag=0;
 62                 day , month , year = definedholiday.split('-')
 63                 holidate = date(int(year) , int(month) , int(day))
 64                 for weekend in self.weekends:
 65                      #check if mentioned holiday lies in defined weekend , shouldnt deduct twice
 66                     if(holidate.isoweekday==weekend):
 67                         flag=1;
 68                         break;
```

I appreciate any assistance anybody an give me, my Python version is 2.4.3

Comment: have you defined a `date` function in your code, or you wanted to use `datetime.datetime.date` function instead

Comment: The code is from a library i got on PyPi, I think you're right and whoever wrote this thing is intending to use datetime.datetime.date function perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

That package is not well-written. If you look at [the code](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/B/BusinessHours/BusinessHours-1.2.tar.gz#md5=514ecbb23d4aa8e0cea9f013e28c8fce), it doesn't import anything, but tries to use functions from mobules that need to be imported (e.g. `date`).

It looks like the person who submitted the package just didn't do a good job. You might need to implement your own code to do this (perhaps using some of their logic as a general guide).

Comment: Hi Amber, I was hoping to avoid having to re-write it :(  I thought there might have been an easy fix, perhaps it wasn't importing the right datetime module due to my python version or something. Or i needed to change it to datetime.datetime.date like avasal mentioned above.

Comment: Well, you could try just patching the library - add the right imports to the library's code file.